# Putting four plots in two rows

Tags: plotting

I want the following four plots to be displayed in two rows. That P1 and P2 in the top row and P3 and P4 in the bottom row.

```
 P1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", Rotate["Sin(x)", 0 Degree]}, ImageSize -> 250]
P2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", Rotate["Cos(x)", 0 Degree]}, ImageSize -> 250]
P3 = Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", Rotate["ArcSin(x)", 0 Degree]}, ImageSize -> 250]
P4 = Plot[ArcCos[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", Rotate["ArcCos(x)", 0 Degree]}, 
  ImageSize -> 250]
```

Is it possible to do it in $Mathematica$ ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Labeled` or `PlotLabel` for that

```
P1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
   Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "Sin(x)"}, 
   ImageSize -> 250, PlotLabel -> "(a)"];
P2 = Labeled[Plot[Cos[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True},
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "Cos(x)"}, ImageSize -> 250], "(b)"];
P3 = Labeled[Plot[ArcSin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "ArcSin(x)"}, ImageSize -> 250], "(c)", {Left}];
P4 = Labeled[Plot[ArcCos[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True},
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "ArcCos(x)"}, ImageSize -> 250], "(d)", {Right}];
```

For extra artistic touch (as suggested by @Nasser)

```
plot=Grid[{{P1, P2}, {P3, P4}}, Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> All, FrameStyle -> LightGray]

Export["plot.png",plot]
```

[image]

Check  [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html) documentation for more options.

Also, check [`GraphicsGrid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsGrid.html) (suggested by @march).

Comment: Also, `GraphicsGrid`, that allows a little more fine-tuned control such as `ImageSize`.

Comment: +1, but when I do this sort of thing, I like to add `Spacings` and lightgray frame, makes the plot looks little more pretty as in `Grid[{{P1, P2}, {P3, P4}}, Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> All, 
 FrameStyle -> LightGray]`

Comment: Thanks, friends. Can I label the plots as (a), (b) (c) and (d) such that the label appears below each plot? Also, is it possible to save the entire Grid as a single figure?

Comment: @Jee just add `//Rasterize ` at the end

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys.